# how to extract text in between every two regex words in a large chunk of text in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with just one column 'text' that contains a large chunk of text structured like:

```
text
"dd ee Apple A1 a b c d Apple A2 e f g Apple B1 hi g Apple C1 r 5 6 Apple D1..."
```

How to I get below output:

```
text_new
Apple A1 a b c d 
Apple A2 e f g 
Apple B1 hi g
Apple C1 r 5 6
Apple D1 ...
...
```

in the sense that every row include all texts between every occurance of the regex "Apple[space][letter][number]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and specific regex pattern:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text_col': df['text'].str.findall(r'(Apple .+?)(?=Apple|$)')[0]})
```

---

```
            text_col
0  Apple A1 a b c d 
1    Apple A2 e f g 
2     Apple B1 hi g 
3    Apple C1 r 5 6 
4       Apple D1...
```

Or with `Series.str.extractall`:

```
df['text'].str.extractall(r'(Apple .+?)(?=Apple|$)').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
                   0
0  Apple A1 a b c d 
1    Apple A2 e f g 
2     Apple B1 hi g 
3    Apple C1 r 5 6 
4       Apple D1...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
s = "Apple A1 a b c d Apple A2 e f g Apple B1 hi g Apple C1 r 5 6 Apple D1..."

result = ["Apple " + p
          for p in s.split("Apple ") if p]

print('\n'.join(result))
```

*One-liner* approach:

```
print(*(f'Apple {p}' for p in "Apple A1 a b c d Apple A2 e f g Apple B1 hi g Apple C1 r 5 6 Apple D1...".split("Apple ") if p), sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
Apple A1 a b c d 
Apple A2 e f g 
Apple B1 hi g 
Apple C1 r 5 6 
Apple D1...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't need a regular expression, but this should work if " Apple" might appear somewhere else and it has to be done on Apple[space][letter][digit].

```
import re
    
text = "Apple A1 a b c d Apple A2 e f g Apple B1 hi g Apple C1 r 5 6 Apple D1..."

re.sub(r' (Apple [A-Z]\d)', r'\n\1', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not like wrecking my head with complicated `regex`. So let me offer an alternative.

Split the string before 'Apple' and remove white spaces with `.strip()`. The result will have one empty element from the start of the `my_str`which can be removed by selecting elements if its not empty. `if substr` at the end of the list comprehension performs this task.

```
my_str = "Apple A1 a b c d Apple A2 e f g Apple B1 hi g Apple C1 r 5 6 Apple D1"

# Split the input at 'Apple'
substrings = [substr.strip() for substr in my_str.split('Apple') if substr]

# add 'Apple' to the beginning of each substring
result = ['Apple ' + substr for substr in substrings]

df = pd.DataFrame({'text_new': result})
```

Output:

```
    text_new
0   Apple A1 a b c d
1   Apple A2 e f g
2   Apple B1 hi g
3   Apple C1 r 5 6
4   Apple D1
```